# Where is ejabberd server configuration file on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, ejabberd

I have installed the Jabbered 15.07 on my MAC OS. After installation, I want to config it by editing the /Applications/ejabberd-15.07/conf/ejabberd.yml. I am not sure whether it is the file I should change, I searched the Internet and found that sb said the configuration is in the folder /etc but I did not found it there. In order to prove that it is the file I want to find, I open the admin interface and add a record in the "ACL" screen. And after that I checked the `ejabberd.yml`, but it remained unchanged. So is it the configuration file of ejabberd, if it is not which file it should be and how to configure it?

Answer (score 4):

The location of the config file depend on how you installed ejabberd.

Apparently, you used binary installer, not make install, so config file is as your expected:

```
/Applications/ejabberd-15.07/conf/ejabberd.yml
```

Admin interface does not change the config file but write in mnesia database. You could configure ejabberd so that database override config file, but this is not a good practice. To make change permanent, you need to edit `ejabberd.yml` file.

Note: You should use latest ejabberd published version if you are starting today (15.11).